# list members of a group in vbs from input

Tags: vbscript

ok so i want to write a user management system for my project in school. i chose vbs since it had to be a script language. one of the features of the script is that it can list the members of a give group. the user inputs a domain in which to look for groups and then it lists them in an input box. the user can then enter a chosen group and the function will give this string to a procedure. this is the part which is not working. i hope someone can help me here, i have been sitting on this for hours....

```
'Funktion zur Verarbeitung der Gruppenverwaltung
Function gruppenVerwaltung
choice = IB ("Gruppenverwaltung" & vbCr & _
    "1. Gruppe hinzufügen" & vbCr & _
    "2. Grupe entfernen" & vbCr & _
    "3. Gruppen anzeigen" & vbCr & _
    "4. Lokale Gruppe einer globalen Gruppe zuweisen" & vbCr & _
    "5. Lokale Gruppe aus einer globalen Gruppe entfernen" & vbCr & _
    "6. Mitglieder einer Gruppe hinzufügen" & vbCr & _
    "7. Mitglieder aus einer Gruppe entfernen" & vbCr & _
    "8. Mitglieder einer Gruppe anzeigen" & vbCr & _
    "9. Zurück...")

    If choice = 3 Then
        Do
            strDomain = IBText("Domäne eingeben: ", "Input")
        Loop Until strDomain <> ""
        gruppenAnzeigen(strDomain)
    End If

    If choice = 9 Then
        main
    End If

    If choice < 1 Or choice > 9 Then
        MsgBox "Falsche Eingabe! Nochmal..."
        gruppenVerwaltung
    End If

    If choice = 8 Then
    strDomain = IBText("Domäne der Gruppe eingeben: ")
        Set objComputer = GetObject ("WinNT://" & strDomain)
        objComputer.Filter = Array("group")         
        For each objGruppe in objComputer   
            strText = strText & "Name:" & objGruppe.Name & vbCr                         
        Next

        Do
            strGruppe = IBText(strText & vbCr & "Gruppe eingeben: ")
        Loop Until strGruppe <> ""
        strGruppe = "LDAP://CN=" & strGruppe
        mitgliederAnzeigen(strGruppe)
    End If
End Function

'Prozedur zur Anzeige aller Mitglieder einer Gruppe
Sub mitgliederAnzeigen(strGruppe)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Set objGroup = GetObject(strGruppe)   
For Each Member in objGroup.Members 
    WScript.echo Member.cn & " ; " & Member.displayName  
Next
End Sub
```

so basically the function (gruppenVerwaltung) is where the menu sits. if the user chooses entry 8 then he must enter a domain and then gets all the groups in that domain in a list (inputbox). he can then choose a group, which is stored as string.

when the function then calls the procedure (mitgliederAnzeigen), it tries apply GetObject on the string which holds the group name. this is where i get an error "the domain could not be found or a connection could not be established" or something along those lines (sorry the error message is in german, error code is 8007054B).

i already looked at code online but the user always has to change the group manually in the code (something with "LDAP\cn=groupName", i have tried formatting the string in this style but apparently it doesnt work either.

thanks for any help!

edit: ok now i upgraded my pc to be a domain controller, i get a different error since the upgrade (code 80072020). it occurs in the same line as before (Set objGroup = GetObject(strGruppe))

Answer (score 0):

While this does not use the approach taken in the question, the net.exe utility manipulates groups.  net.exe may be called from vbscript via the Run method.
For more information:

C:> net help group

NET GROUP must be run on a domain controller.

With regard to obtaining results in VBscript, see [How to redirect command-Line output](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278411)